# How to pick up input in Android?

Tags: android

How do I read input from the touchscreen in Android?

Comment: You need to define this more. Are you looking to do character recognition? Most of the time the OS takes care of all the recognition issues and you just interact with the controls programmatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a very broad question, so I will give you the very broad answer of read [Handling UI Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) on the Android Developers site.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you use this listener:
[OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)